# Why does inserting a space with {} only work some of the time?

Tags: spacing, footnotes

I was just trying to customize my footnotes and noticed some strange (to me, at least) behavior. Usually, if I'm inserting a one-character white space I'll simply insert a pair of empty curly braces like so `{}`. Trying to do this with `\thefootnote`, however, produced no space. Compare:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}\hspace{1em}}

\begin{document}

Some dummy text.\footnote{This one works.}

\end{document}
```

to

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}{}}

\begin{document}

Some dummy text.\footnote{This one produces no space.}

\end{document}
```

Why is it that empty curly braces produce no space here? In general, when should I not expect empty braces to produce a white space? Is this an instance of some more general TeX phenomenon?

Comment: `{}` doesn't produce any space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`{}` produces no space, it just starts and ends a group (or in other contexts delimits an argument)

What you are probably thinking about is that in, say, `\LaTeX is` the space is ignored as terminating the macro, so never produces a space token (so does not produce space in the output), but in `\LaTeX{} is` the macro name is terminated by `{` so the  character does make a space token (and so makes space in the output).

If you want a space in the definition you show, just use a space:

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote} }
 %                                           ^
```

Comment: Hah! A space to produce a space, why didn't I think of that! Good to know why the spaces I was inserting (which, you were right to note were all after macros which ignore the space as terminating the macro) were working even though `{}` doesn't insert a space.